# Django - How to fix unique constraint fields

Tags: python, django

I'm making a hobby project and I've got the following model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        # my intention is that one user cannot have more than one group with the same name
        unique_together = ('name', 'user')
```

I would like to make it possible for the user to create new groups by using this generic class based view.

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from groups.models import Group

class GroupCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Group
    fields = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ideas:list')
    template_name = 'groups/group_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(GroupCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

As long as I don't try to make an error by sending an existing group's name, everything works fine. But if I send an existing group's name (same user!), I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /groups/create
UNIQUE constraint failed: groups_group.name, groups_group.user_id
```

Why does it occur? How could I fix it or catch the error?

I'm using Django 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at the time of creating the group.

```
from django.contrib import messages

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']

    if Group.objects.filter(name=name, user=self.request.user).exists():
        messages.error(self.request, 'An Group with this name already exists.')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
    else:
        form.instance.name= name

    messages.success(self.request, 'Congratulations!! Your Group is created successfully.')
    return super(GroupCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I don't want the group's name to be unique. I want it to be unique together with the user. So one user can have only one group with the same name. But two user can have any group with the same name.

Comment: @Johnny, I have updated my answer. Have a look into it.

Comment: Feel glad that it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I found a bug, one line fixed.

Comment: What, you did filter(name=name, user=user)??

Comment: Yes, because my intention is that ONE user cannot have more group with the same name. But there can be groups with the same name if the user is NOT the same.

Comment: That's fine, I knew that but I recommend the other way, that keep the group name unique and add multiple users to any of group and also a user can be pary of many group. That's why. If you want other way then I have updated my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you declared a constraint:

```
unique_together = ('name', 'user')
```

Just remove this constraint.